# How do I compute the standard error of the posterior mode?

Tags: bayesian, standard-error, posterior

How do I compute the standard error of the posterior mode? I've tried checking various sources like Google and Bing, but I haven't been able to answer my question.

Comment: What for do you need it? Why not just take the posterior distribution as-is and e.g. report it's descriptive statistics? If you *really* need SE, then probably bootstrap is the method of choice, but it sounds like an overkill.

Comment: Standard error is a frequentist concept.  If you are applying Bayesian methods the posterior distribution explains the uncertainty in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Estimating the posterior mode is a common approach in psychometrics. Frequentist approaches mention the posterior mode and nothing else. From a Bayesian framework, if I am reporting a posterior mode, then I need also to report some measure of uncertainty of that estimate.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the posterior mode would be an unknown quantity to begin with (such that it needs to be estimated).  If you have a likelihood and prior, this fully determines the posterior distribution, which determines its mode.  Can you explain why the posterior mode is unknown?  (I.e., what information are you missing to compute it?)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the standard error is a concept in frequentist statistics. If you want to report some measure of uncertainty, I would suggest that you construct a [Credible Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval).

Now, credible intervals are not unique as you can choose to "cut" the posterior distribution in many different ways and get different intervals every time you do it. Hence, given that you are interested on the posterior mode and assuming that your posterior distribution is unimodal, I recommend that you take the highest posterior density interval (HPDI) which is is narrowest credible interval and includes the mode.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Vas is correct. Credible intervals are the most Bayesian way. However I understand there is sometimes a need to present a simple index of uncertainty.

My first thought is to estimate the fisher information / Hessian (making a variational approximation). The square root of the diagonals of this should give a 'standard error'-like quantity, in the same units as the parameter of interest. For posterior $q(\theta)$,
$$
H_{ij} =\left[ \frac{\partial^2 \ \mathrm{log}(q)}{\partial\theta_{ij}} \right]
$$
$$
std. err. \approx \sqrt{H_{ii}}
$$
Most optimisation tools give Hessian e.g. `fmincon`.
Note the caveats with this approach - assumes unimodal, gaussian densities. And isn't Bayesian.
The benefits - works with multivariate posteriors, and you can see axes of correlations between parameters as eigenvectors of $H$.

Here is a more formal answer:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5608466/